# Are all projective modules injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I think it is wrong, but I have several steps to prove it.

R-Module P is projective

$\rightarrow$ P is a term of direct sum for certain free module.

$\rightarrow$ P is a term of direct sum for certain module.

$\rightarrow$ P is injective.

Is this proof wrong?

Comment: Why does the last implication hold?

Comment: There is no justification for that third step, and in fact projective modules are rarely injective. For example an abelian group is projective iff free and injective iff divisible, so the only projective injective group is the trivial group.

Comment: Are the followings wrong? Q is injective ⇔0→Q→M→N→0 exact ⇔M≌ Q⊕N

Comment: You haven't put any quantifiers in that statement. The statement is that $Q$ is injective iff *every* short exact sequence $0 \to Q \to M \to N \to 0$ splits, not just that *some* such short exact sequence splits.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Qiaochu Yuan, I have understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answer added to eliminate it from the unanswered questions list*

---

For posterity, the mistake in the argument above is that of misunderstanding the quantification in a characterization of injectivity.

The solution used the splitting of the sequence $0\to N\to R^n\to P\to 0$ to write $P\oplus N=R^n$, which is ok, but it followed with

> So $P$ is also injective since it is a summand of some module (namely $R^n$ above).

$P$ would be injective if  **for all** exact sequences $0\to P\to M\to N\to 0$ splits, but that is not the case here.

As a case in point, $(2)$ is a projective $\mathbb Z$ module, but obviously it cannot split out of $0\to (2)\to \mathbb Z\to N\to 0$  unless $N$ is already zero.

---

Supplementary material, not really helpful for this question

The condition that "all projective modules are injective" is a characterization of [quasi-Frobenius rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Frobenius_ring).